# Dynamic form not working as expected with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My PHP can't find my jQuery dynamic form, can anyone help me? I have tried to `echo` how many vendor rows there are, but it turns out it just reads the first input row and not the latter. I was hoping that the next row could be read as input so that I could post it to my database

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
  var count = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
    count++;
    $('#total_item').val(count);
    var html_code = '';
    html_code += '<tr id="row_id_' + count + '">';
    html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">' + count + '</span></td>';
    html_code += '<td><textarea  name="vendor[]" id="vendor' + count + '" rows = "5" cols = "20" data-srno="' + count + '" class= "form-control input-sm" ></textarea></td>';
    html_code += '<td><textarea  name="itemdescription[]" id="itemdescription' + count + '" rows = "5" cols = "20" data-srno="' + count + '" class= "form-control input-sm"  ></textarea></td>';
    html_code += '<td><input type= "text" id="order_item_quantity' + count + '" name="order_item_quantity[]" data-srno="' + count + '" class= "form-control input-sm number_only order_item_quantity"></td>';
    html_code += '<td><input type= "text" id="order_item_price' + count + '" name="order_item_price[]" data-srno="' + count + '" class= "form-control input-sm order_item_price"></td>';
    html_code += '<td><input type= "text" 
    id = "order_item_final_amount'+count+'"
    name = "order_item_final_amount[]"
    data -
      srno = "'+count+'"
    class = "form-control input-sm 
    order_item_final_amount " 
    readonly > < /td>';
    html_code += '<td></td>';
    html_code += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_row" 
    id = "'+count+'"
    class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row" > X < /button>  <
      /td>';
    html_code += '</tr>';
    $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function() {
    var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var total_item_amount = $('#order_item_final_amount' + row_id).val();
    var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
    var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) -
      parseFloat(total_item_amount);
    $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
    $('#totcost').text(result_amount);
    $('#row_id_' + row_id).remove();
    $('#poloam1').text(poloam);
    count--;
    $('#total_item').val(count);
  });

  function cal_final_total(count) {
    var final_item_total = 0;
    var grossprofit = 0;
    var grossprofitpercen = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
      var quantity = 0;
      var price = 0;
      var actual_amount = 0;
      var item_total = 0;
      quantity = $('#order_item_quantity' + j).val();
      if (quantity >= 0) {
        price = $('#order_item_price' + j).val();
        if (price >= 0) {
          actual_amount = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
          item_total = parseFloat(actual_amount);
          final_item_total = parseFloat(final_item_total) +
            parseFloat(item_total);
          $('#order_item_final_amount' + j).val(item_total);

        }
      }
    }

    $('#final_total_amt').val(final_item_total);
    polo = $('#poloam1').val();
    grossprofit = parseFloat(polo) - parseFloat(final_item_total);
    $('#grossprofit').val(grossprofit);
    $('#poloamount').text(polo);
    $('#totcost').text(final_item_total);
    grossprofitpercen = parseFloat(grossprofit) / (parseFloat(final_item_total) / 100);
    $('#grossprofitpercen').val(grossprofitpercen.toFixed(2));
  }

  $(document).on('blur', '.order_item_price', function() {
    cal_final_total(count);
  });

  $(document).on('blur', '.grossprofit', function() {
    cal_final_total(count);
  });

  $(document).on('blur', '.grossprofitpercen', function() {
    cal_final_total(count);
  });

  $(document).on('blur', '.final_total_amt', function() {
    cal_final_total(count);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your description is not clear. What exactly about this does not work?

Comment: in my code there's a table, when i click add row, and click enter, it tells me undefined offset. Then i try to echo to count how many row are there, it turns out, only the first row are echo not the one after it.

Comment: so that i know that my original input type are working but not the jquery one

Comment: @user7378014 Do you mean to say you want total tr in $('#total_item') element ?

Comment: <input type="text" name="total_item" id="total_item" value="1" /></td> i use this to confirm the number of rows